# How to get optgroup value from Javascript?

Tags: javascript

```html
<html>
<body>

<select name="lstparameters">
  <optgroup value="100" label="Swedish Cars">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup value="101" label="German Cars">
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
 
</body>
</html>
```

How to get optgroup values from javascript?I want to get 100 and 101 values.

Answer (score 9):

For those like me wanting to get the `optgroup` `label` of the `selected` `option`, do this:

```
document.querySelector('select[name="lstparameters"] option:checked').parentElement.label
```

Having a `select` with an `id` simplifies the selector:

```
document.querySelector('#lstparameters option:checked').parentElement.label
```

Comment: This is the solution for Javascript _alone_. @MarredCheese thank you for answering this years later!

Answer (score 6):

You can get the optgroup elements and read the `value` attribute

```js
var values = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('select[name="lstparameters"] > optgroup')).map(el => el.getAttribute('value'));

alert(values);

//if you want old browser support
var values = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('select[name="lstparameters"] > optgroup')).map(function(el) {
  return el.getAttribute('value')
});
alert(values);
```

```html
<select name="lstparameters">
  <optgroup value="100" label="Swedish Cars">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup value="101" label="German Cars">
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

Comment: Hi Arun, Its getting.How can i get the opt group value of label 'Swedish Cars'?

Comment: @PrinuPhilip `el.getAttribute('label')`

Comment: How to set optgroup value in javascript?. var newOptGroup = document.createElement('optgroup'); newOptGroup.label = 'indian Cars'; newOptGroup.value = '103'; newOptGroup.appendChild(option); here newOptGroup.value = '103' is not working

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.closest()` function to determine the selected `optgroup`

```js
$(function() {
  var selected = $('select option:selected');
  alert(selected.closest('optgroup').attr('value'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<body>

  <select name="lstparameters">
    <optgroup value="100" label="Swedish Cars">
      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab" selected>Saab</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup value="101" label="German Cars">
      <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </optgroup>
  </select>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: That's jQuery, the OP hasn't asked for a Jquery solution. Adding a whole library just to read a single attribute is massive overkill

Answer (score 0):

@Arun P Johny shows already some ways which are nice and simple.

I just want to provide some other methods.

For really old browsers (< IE9):

```
var dropdown = document.getElementsByName('lstparameters')[0];
var optgroups = dropdown.getElementsByTagName('optgroup');

var results = [];
for(var i = 0; i < optgroups.length; i++) {
    results.push(optgroups[i].getAttribute('value'));
}

alert(results);
```

And another option with [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) and [array prototype map](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
var results = [].map.call(document.querySelectorAll('select optgroup'), x => { return x.getAttribute('value') });

alert(results);
```

**Update:**

To get the value by label you can either add the label to yours query selector (`optgroup[label="Swedish Cars"]`) or for the for loop method see this:

```
var dropdown = document.getElementsByName('lstparameters')[0];
var optgroups = dropdown.getElementsByTagName('optgroup');

for(var i = 0; i < optgroups.length; i++) {
    if (optgroups[i].getAttribute('label') == 'Swedish Cars') {
        alert(optgroups[i].getAttribute('value'));
        return;
    };
}

alert(results);
```

Comment: How can i get optgroup value from label name?.

Comment: How to set optgroup value in javascript?. var newOptGroup = document.createElement('optgroup'); newOptGroup.label = 'indian Cars'; newOptGroup.value = '103'; newOptGroup.appendChild(option); here newOptGroup.value = '103' is not working

Comment: @Prinu Philip You have to append it so your dropdown (select) too. But this is really different to your question postet in this topic. Just open a new question.